# Show content only if user is an owner of this content (node)

Tags: 7, panels

How do I show a node "only if a user is an owner of the node" with Panels/Page Manager' Variants and its Visibility Rules (right icon on each content)?

[image]
[image]

Comment: you may check that condition in your view first.

Comment: @Kojo ok but to be more precise... I can only guess - it is rather not Access and not Relationships, it might be Contextual Filters.. but still don't know how.

Comment: @Kojo got it - accomplished with CONTEXTUAL FILTERS and Content: Author uid. thanks for directions.

Comment: Glad you found it yourself. You're welcome ☺

Answer (score 0):

If possible then create your own permission which should be visible under 
**Variants » Basic » Selection rules ** section. For creating panel permission, check following steps:
1. Create folder structure like module -> plugins -> access -> filename.inc
2. Add following function and hooks under that file:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Plugin to provide access control based upon role membership.
 */

/**
 * Plugins are described by creating a $plugin array which will be used
 * by the system that includes this file.
 */
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t("Community: Access"),
  'description' => t('Control access by community.'),
  'callback' => 'dc_visibility_ctools_access_check',
  'default' => array('community' => array()),
  'settings form' => 'dc_visibility_ctools_access_settings',
  'settings form submit' => 'dc_visibility_ctools_access_settings_submit',
  'summary' => 'dc_visibility_ctools_access_summary',
  'all contexts' => TRUE,
);

/**
 * Settings form for the 'by role' access plugin
 */
function dc_visibility_ctools_access_settings($form, &$form_state, $conf) {

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Compress the community allowed to the minimum.
 */
function dc_visibility_ctools_access_settings_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['values']['settings']['community'] = array_keys(array_filter($form_state['values']['settings']['community']));
}

/**
 * Check for access.
 */
function dc_visibility_ctools_access_check($conf, $context) {

}

function dc_visibility_ctools_access_summary($conf, $context){

}
```